# Email Pdf attachments to Google sheet

Tags: email, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am looking for something that allows me from a mail PDF attachment to get a data in a google sheet.

We all often get PDF attachments in our email and it will be great if we get the entire data in a google sheet.

DO let me know if there is anything like this

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If you're just looking for a finished tool to run manually for extracting things, maybe superuser.com might be a better fit (which also works with Stack Overflow/StackExchange accounts). This site is more for programming-related questions for writing programs yourself. I apologize if I misread your question.

Answer (score 0):

### Explanation:

Your question is very broad and it is impossible to give a specific answer because that answer would depend on the pdf but also on the data you want to fetch from that, besides all the other details you skipped to mention.

- Here I will provide a general code snippet which you can use to get the pdf from the gmail attachments and then convert it to text (string). For this text you can use some regular expressions (which have to be very specific on your use case) to get the desired information and then put it in your sheet.

### Code snippet:

The main code will this one. You should only modify this code:

```
function myFunction() {
  const queryString = "label:unread from example@gmail.com" // use your email query
  const threads = GmailApp.search(queryString);
  const threadsMessages = GmailApp.getMessagesForThreads(threads);
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();

  for (thr = 0, thrs = threads.length; thr < thrs; ++thr) {
   let messages = threads[thr].getMessages(); 
     for (msg = 0, msgs = messages.length; msg < msgs; ++msg) { 
       let attachments = messages[msg].getAttachments();
        for (att = 0, atts = attachments.length; att < atts; ++att) { 
          let attachment_Name = attachments[att].getName();
      
      let filetext = pdfToText( attachments[att], {keepTextfile: false} );
      Logger.log(filetext)
      // do something with filetext
      // build some regular expression that fetches the desired data from filetext
      // put this data to the sheet
   }}}
}
```

and `pdfToText` is a function implemented by [Mogsdad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1677912/mogsdad) which you can find [here](https://gist.github.com/mogsdad/e6795e438615d252584f). Just copy paste the code snippet provided in that link together with `myFunction` I posted in this answer. Also you have some options which you can use that are very well explained in the link I provided. Important thing to note, to use this library you need to enable the `Drive API` from the resources.

This will get you started and if you face any issues down the road which you can't find the solution for, you should create a new post here with the specific details of the problem.